# How to get telegram chat id

Tags: telegram-bot

So i have this python code that figures out channel chat id to send message for multiple channels in a given list.

I only have the channel invite link

I still didn't figure out how can i get the channel id by the name only.

```
import os
import telebot
API_KEY = os.environ['API_KEY']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)
a=input("edit msg.txt to send the msg if done press enter")
message=open("message.txt","a+")
bot.send_message(chat_id,message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer to use Telegram API together with `javascript` and `axios` library then you might consider the following:

```
const method = 'get'

const headers: any = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  timestamp: +new Date(),
}

const options = { headers: { ...headers } }

const urlTelegramBase =
  'https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABCDEF'

const urlGetUpdates = `${urlTelegramBase}/getUpdates`
const username = 'user_name'

const {
  data: { result: messages },
} = await axios[method](urlGetUpdates, options)

const chat_id = messages.find(
  messageBlock => messageBlock.message.chat.username === username
).message.chat.id

console.info('chat_id': chat_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getChat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat) method to resolve a channel username to the chat id. You can also just send the message using the username - see the docs of [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) and e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33841795/10606962).

Comment: i only have the channel invite link

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do it then, at least not with pure bot api.